# MVC CORE 5 Boolean Radio Button asp-for Binding for Model.Property not checking on Get

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Radio Buttons don't get selected / checked on Get.
I can submit and save data from radio buttons correctly, but when retrieving patient's by ID the code I share does not check my radio buttons.
The ajax.post submits correct values though.

Index.cshtml

```
@model ITHealth.ViewModels.PatientViewModel

<!--tab contents-->
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    
    
    <!--social history-->
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="socHistTab" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="soc-hist-tab">
        <partial name="PatientIntake/_SocialHistory.cshtml" />
    </div>
    
    
</div>
```

_SocialHistory.cshtml

```
@model ITHealth.ViewModels.PatientViewModel
<input class="mr-2" type="radio" id="smokingYes" value="true" asp-for="SocialHistory.Smoking" /><label for="smokingYes">Yes</label>
                        <input class="ml-3 mr-3" type="radio" id="smokingNo" value="false" asp-for="SocialHistory.Smoking" /><label for="smokingNo">No</label>
```

My Model is as follows:

```
public class PatientViewModel
{      
    public SocialHistoryModel SocialHistory { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
[Table("PatientSocialHistories")]
public class SocialHistoryModel
{
    [Key]
    public Guid SocialHistoryID { get; set; }
    public Guid PatientId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PatientId")]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual Patients Patient { get; set; }
    public bool Smoking { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index(Guid? id)
    {

        PatientViewModel patient = new PatientViewModel();

        if (id.HasValue)
        {
            patient.Demographic = patientBLL.GetPatient(id.Value);
            patient.InsurancesP = patientBLL.GetInsurances(patient.Demographic.Patient.PrimaryInsuranceID.ToString());
            patient.ALFs = patientBLL.GetALFs(patient.Demographic.ALFID.ToString());
            patient.Genders = patientBLL.GetGender(patient.Demographic.GenderID.ToString());
            patient.Languages = patientBLL.GetLanguages(patient.Demographic.PrefLangID.ToString());
            patient.PrefContacts = patientBLL.GetPrefCont(patient.Demographic.PrefContactID.ToString());
            patient.States = patientBLL.GetStates(patient.Demographic.StateID.ToString());
            patient.PatientFullName = patient.Demographic.FirstName + " " + patient.Demographic.LastName;
        }
        else
        {
            patient.Demographic = new PatientDemographics();
            patient.InsurancesP = _adminBLL.GetInsuranceProviderSelectList();
            patient.ALFs = _adminBLL.GetALFSelectList();
            patient.Genders = _adminBLL.GetGenderList();
            patient.Languages = _adminBLL.GetActiveLanguages().Select(l => new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem(l.Name, l.LangId.ToString())).ToList();
            patient.PrefContacts = _adminBLL.GetPreferredContactList();
            patient.States = _adminBLL.GetActiveStates().Select(s => new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem(s.Name, s.StateId.ToString())).ToList();
            // Set Value here
        }

        patient.AllInsuranceCarriers = _adminBLL.GetInsuranceProviderSelectList();
        patient.AllPreferredContactMethods = _adminBLL.GetPreferredContactList();
        patient.ReligionList = _adminBLL.GetReligionList();
        patient.MaritalStatusList = _adminBLL.GetMaritalStatusList();
        patient.EthnicityList = _adminBLL.GetEthnicityList();
        patient.PatientContactTypes = patientBLL.GetPatientContactTypeSelectList();
        patient.SocialHistory = patientBLL.GetSocialHistory(id);
        ViewBag.GetRelatives = Utility.Helper.GetRelatives();
        return View(patient);
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Tiaan Hugo van der Merwe, it could works well in my project. Please set breakpoint to line: `patient.SocialHistory = patientBLL.GetSocialHistory(id);` and check if SocialHistory has value or not.

Comment: Hi @Rena. 
My ajax post saves the radio button accordingly to 1 for Yes and 0 for No.
When I retrieve GetSocialHistory(id) the SocialHistory property in the ViewModel is either true if 1 has been saved or 0 if false has been saved.

The Radio inputs though does not seem to get Selected or checked based on the boolean value.

Comment: Hi, what is your ajax post? I need confirm with your requirement first. From your question, It seems the any of two radio button are not checked when the Index page load,does it your requirement?But, what is the relationship with the ajax post? I am a bit confused.

Comment: Hi @Rena. I have solved my issue. There were two of the same views existing simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

There existed two of the same views simultaneously.